# What's the Combination?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, password

Hacker Harry really wants to get into the server room at a local dot com company, so he dressed up as a phone repairman and planted some bugs in the break room to listen in on the workers. Sure enough, against all security common sense, he hears two employees discussing the entry codes!

> "So the code to get into the server room is CentOS right?"
>
> "For the main door, yes, but don't forget we added a code to the
> second door, and the rack door itself as well."
>
> "Oh, that's right. Uhh, it was Tomcat and NodeJS, right?"
>
> "Yup, but remember, memorize it, don't write it down!"

Hacker Harry couldn't believe his luck. That very night he broke into the office, but to his chagrin the lock on the server room door was a combination lock! It had 100 numbers on the dial, everything from 00 to 99, but then what in the world did the codes mean?

Quick! Before Harry gets caught by security, what is the correct combination to the three doors, and how do the codes provide the combination?

**Hint 1:**

> The combination lock follows the standard setup. That is, it requires three numbers to open, so each of the three combination will be comprised of three numbers.

Comment: See the information given can lead to many answers If i understood correctly each door has a lock of 3 numbers each from 00 to 99 . One answer could be these numbers could be the date of first release of these softwares

Comment: There is no knowledge tag, so assume you don't need to know any details that aren't directly in the puzzle. The passwords don't have to be software, they don't even have to be real words

Comment: @AakashMathur I was thinking more like the current releases of those softwares

Comment: Yeah it could also be but as the problem maker said it would not require any knowledge, mostly i think wordplay or something

Comment: Those are all 6 letters, and we have 6 digits in the combination.

Comment: Yes, the link between the number of letters and digits is significant. There is a hint in the story that point towards how to translate from letters to digits, although it might be less obvious than I originally anticipated

Comment: It seems to me that there are a *lot* of ways that letters could be converted into numbers, and nothing in particular pointing to the correct one. Without an example, this seems very much like "guess what I'm thinking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming

> the word **phone** is important,

we could translate each letter as follows:

> ABC=2, DEF=3, GHI=4, JKL=5, MNO=6, PQRS=7, TUV=8, WXYZ=9

which gives the decoded result of

> CentOS = **23 - 68 - 67**

> Tomcat = **86 - 62 - 28**

> NodeJS = **66 - 33 - 57**

Comment: This was my intent, but I clearly underestimated the wide variety of possible and plausible answers

Answer (score 3):

I'll go ahead and make a try at this.

1st lock:

> 8-34-34

2nd lock

> 35-16-21

3rd lock

> 19-9-29

Method:

> convert letter to number using standard a1z26 encoding.  Add each pair of letters.  centos  3-5-14-20-15-19  8-34-34

> or does capitalization matter?